# Hook to change Author Info

Tags: hooks, author

Is there a hook or filter that will allow me to change the author of a post when someone views the page?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean you want the displayed author to be somebody else than the post author? That would involve an extra custom field to store the second author in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently "the_author" is an appropriate filter.

Also, $author is apparently a universal variable, so this code worked out fine:

```
add_filter("the_author", "change_author");

function change_author($author) {
    $author = "NEW AUTHOR!";

    return $author;
}
```